# Can there be arithmetic within a MySQL query's field names?

Tags: mysql, math

I'm trying to find a way to return a field in a query that involves arithmetic operating on the field directly in the query.

For instance;

```
SELECT (number-1) FROM Numbers;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine, what does it do that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: these kind of stuff you can just play around and see what works. there is no harm.

Comment: I guess I'm just being lazy, I do have a test.php file in my html directory I could have used, I just needed a quick answer. Many thanks!

Comment: *"I guess I'm just being lazy"*: that's what the tooltip on the downvote button seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's an example proving it:
[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e39d/1)